# Difference between One-Mnay relationship & Many-Many relationship

Tags: sqlite, relationship, table-relationships

I am just confused about One-One relationship and Many-Many relationship. Well if I have a users table and a course table, Do I have to add a third table to make it Many-Many relationship or I can just connect them with foreign keys and primary keys? I hope my question is clear to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**One-to-Many example :-**

[image]

**Many to One example :-**

[image]

Comment: I understand this, but how about making tables? Do I need to add 3rd table to control the other 2 or just I can assign foreign keys in one table and primary keys in the other one?

Comment: My point of view, we will go for primary & foreign key relationship. But it's depend upon project complexity & requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Teacher teaches students is one to many relationship
And students learning from the teacher is many to one relationship
May be your dought is clear now!!

Answer (score 0):

You are asking about many to many relationship. In this imaginary relation you have to follow following steps

1-create two tables(users,courses)
2-make third table which is called pivot table . that will contains the foreighn keys of both tables that shows the relation b/w two tables.

3-You also have to make relationships of one-to-many in both tables(users,courses).

I hope this helps if not visit this link you will understand.

https://onlinewebtutorblog.com/laravel-8-many-to-many-eloquent-relationship-tutorial/